# Disabling smart search/regex with Jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I use the jquery datatable filtering like as bellow.

```
filterColumnDetails = [{
        sSelector : "#name",
        type : "select"
    }, {
        sSelector : "#address",
        type : "select",
    }, null,];
```

But If I select the word "Ann" for name filtering it give the output "Ann" and "AnnSaman".
But I need only to show "Ann".

Can anyone help me, how to disable the smart search in jquery datatable.

Comment: @Avinash Raj: Can you please tell me any idea how can I achieve it?

Comment: the person who down it, please let me know the reason why did you down it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix this issue, I enable the RegExp filter as bellow.

```
$('#nameSel').on('change', 'select', function () {

        var name= $(this).val();

        oTable.fnFilter( "^" + name + "$", 1, true);
});
```

**Note: nameSel is an id of the drop down.**

I enabled the RegExp filter by passing true as bellow.

```
oTable.fnFilter( "^" + name + "$", 1, true);
```